# Automapper map multiple dtos to the same model

Tags: c#, automapper, dto

I have a model that is my base model that has numerous fields in it.  I then have 4 DTOs that are parts of that model.  I want to map all of them to the model in the end but each time I map it overwrites the previous mapping.

For example

```
_model = new GenericModel();
_model.ExampleNotInDTO = "This Gets Overwritten being set previously";

//First Mapping below overwrites the property I set above and 
// sets only the fields in the business dto.
Mapper.CreateMap<BusinessDto, GenericModel>();
_model = Mapper.Map<BusinessDto, GenericModel>(searchResultsQuery.BusinessDto);

//Now doing another mapping just below it nulls out all the previous 
// stuff and only fills in the events dto.
Mapper.CreateMap<EventsDto, GenericModel>();
_model = Mapper.Map<EventsDto, GenericModel>(searchResultsQuery.EventsDto);
```

How would be the best way to get all 4 of my dtos (only 2 above for example sake) into the same _model object?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're asking AutoMapper to create a new object each time when you call `Map` that way.  You can create the object manually and use `Map<TSource, TDestination>(TSource source, TDestination destination)` to do what you want.  For example:

```
Mapper.Map<BusinessDto, GenericModel>(searchResultsQuery.BusinessDto, _model);
```

or

```
Mapper.Map(searchResultsQuery.BusinessDto, _model);
```

Comment: Thanks.  This is what I needed.  You can drop the types too Mapper.Map(searchResultsQuery.BusinessDto, _model);